# How can I use Mysql command line client in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: mysql

I just upgraded Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 (installed within windows 7)  and during installation the process asked me to set my Mysql root password. According to Ubuntu Documentation, Mysql server is pre-istalled in Ubuntu version 12.04.

However, when I search for "Mysql command line client" in the Dash Home, the following files are shown:

1. `Mysql 5.5 command Line Client.lnk`
2. `qa_auth client.dll`
3. `mysqlclient.lib`
4. `client plugin.h`

When I open the first option on the list (Mysql 5.5 command Line Client.lnk), the following two error messages are shown:

1. `Path Not Found`
2. `There is no Windows Program configured to run this type of file.`

The other 3 options are of no help too.

Please help by explaining to me how can I use Mysql Command Line Client (the CUI for Mysql) in my Ubuntu version?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What CUI do you mean exactly? Is it the `mysql` command from the command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open a terminal, e.g. by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Then run the command

```
mysql
```

Edit: Like mentioned in a comment, you can specify a user using the -u argument. If this user is password protected, also add a -p, then you'll be prompted for a password. For example if you wanted to log in with a user called root:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: This error is shown: "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'home'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Comment: Actually it is saying it does NOT have a password so "mysql -uroot -p" should work. If not then force it, something like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120718/cant-log-to-mysql?rq=1

Comment: @LuisAlvarado No it's not. It says it's *attempting* to authenticate without any password and user `'home'@'localhost'`. It's probably the wrong user as well as it's using the local shell username by default. By default a MySQL installation on Ubuntu has a `root@localhost` (used as just `root` to log in from `localhost`) and a password provided at installation time (= the administrative password asked by debconf).

Comment: yes correct, read it wrong.