# How could I successfully log in under a non-existent user account?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to setup [ownCloud](https://owncloud.com/) in a test lab. I somehow managed to create a 'owncloud' user (which is fine). The account has an empty password (I'm not sure how that happened), so I'm trying to set one:

[image: MySQL and 'No Current User' after logging in as a user]

For reasons that I don't understand (I'm not a database guru), the database is telling me there's no current user even though I logged in using the 'owncloud' test account.

Any ideas how to make MySQL behave as expected?

EDIT: I was wrong about the user 'owncloud'. It was not created though the ownCloud setup (I think I confused the server's name ('owncloud') with the user ('owncloud') because I expected it to be there).

New question: how in the world could I successfully log in under a non-existent user account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following result of the `CURRENT_USER()`

```
mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+
| CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+
| @localhost     |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

says that you're **currently using the database as *anonymous user***. A freshly installed MySQL db has the following user entries in its mysql.user table:

```
mysql> SELECT user,host,password from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
| user             | host            | password                                  |
+------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
| root             | localhost       | *........................................ |
| root             | xxxx            | *........................................ |
| root             | 127.0.0.1       | *........................................ |
| root             | ::1             | *........................................ |
|                  | localhost       |                                           |
|                  | xxxxx           |                                           |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost       | *........................................ |
+------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

There are some root accounts (password-secured) and two anonymous accounts allowing a logon from localhost (the xxxxx entry is the machine's hostname).

If there's an entry in the user table lacking username and password, the following rule applies:

> If the User value is blank, it matches any user name. **If the user
> table row that matches an incoming connection has a blank user name,
> the user is considered to be an anonymous user with no name, not a
> user with the name that the client actually specified.** This means that
> a blank user name is used for all further access checking for the
> duration of the connection (that is, during Stage 2).
>
> (see the [MySQL docs, "6.2.4. Access Control, Stage 1: Connection Verification"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connection-access.html))

In general, after installing MySQL, you should take notice of the following part of the documentation: "[2.11.2. Securing the Initial MySQL Accounts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html)".

Comment: Great, thanks tohuwawohu. So I'm clear: its a feature, not a security bug ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in set password command. You have to specify set password for whom..The correct syntax is

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'user-name-here'@'hostname-name-here' = PASSWORD('new-password-here');
```

Comment: Thanks maythux. According to [SET PASSWORD Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html): "With no FOR user clause, this statement sets the password for the current user." But I did try it with the `FOR user clause` and got the same result.